# Nginx if flask app not running redirect to different url

Tags: nginx, flask

Some times flask app server may not be running which the page will just say server not reached. Is there any way we can have Nginx to redirect to different url if flask app is not able to be reached

Comment: [PWAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_web_application) can do this client side.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of dynamic change of proxying is not possible in Nginx directly. One way you could do is by having a dedicated service(application) that takes care of this by polling your primary flask endpoint at regular intervals.

If the is a negatory response then your service could simply change the nginx config and then send a `HUP` signal to the nginx process which in turn reloads nginx with the newly available config. This method is pretty efficient and fast.

In case you are making this service in Python, you could use [`signals` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html) to send the signal to nginx master process and also the [`nginxparser` library](https://github.com/fatiherikli/nginxparser) to play around with the nginx config